# Adding custom UIView to the view controller causes it to disappear in the storyboard

Tags: swift, uiview, storyboard, custom-controls, custom-view

I created a custom UIView and then added it to a number of viewControllers. The view controller become glitchy and do not render in the storyboard. I just see the view controllers' outlines and no content.  If I remove the custom view then all goes back to normal.

Can someone please take a look at my custom view code and see if I am doing anything wrong?  Thank you so much.

```
import UIKit

@IBDesignable
class ProgressView: UIView {

@IBOutlet var contentView: UIView!
@IBInspectable var percentageProgress: CGFloat = 0.0 {
  didSet {
    self.setGradient()
  }
}

override init(frame: CGRect) {
  super.init(frame: frame)
  commonInit()
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
  super.init(coder: aDecoder)
  commonInit()
}

private func commonInit() {
  Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("ProgressView", owner: self, options: nil)
  addSubview(contentView)
  contentView.frame = self.bounds
  contentView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]

  setGradient()

}

private func setGradient() {

  if let sublayers = self.contentView.layer.sublayers {
    for sublayer in sublayers {
      sublayer.removeFromSuperlayer()
    }
  }

  let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
  gradientLayer.colors = [UIColor(#colorLiteral(red: 0.3935321569, green: 0.3986310661, blue: 0.6819975972, alpha: 1)).cgColor, UIColor(#colorLiteral(red: 0.1705667078, green: 0.649338007, blue: 0.5616513491, alpha: 1)).cgColor]
  gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.5)
  gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1.0, y: 0.5)

  gradientLayer.cornerRadius = contentView.frame.height / 2

  contentView.layer.cornerRadius = contentView.frame.height / 2
  self.contentView.layer.insertSublayer(gradientLayer, at: 0)




  gradientLayer.frame = CGRect(x: contentView.frame.minX, y: contentView.frame.minY, 
 width: self.contentView.frame.maxX * (percentageProgress ?? 1.0), height: 
 contentView.frame.maxY)

  self.contentView.setNeedsDisplay()
 }

}
```

Comment: what is contentView ?

Comment: Two things jump out at me. First, in `commonInit` you are setting a frame. Are you *sure* there's a frame to set? Setting frames in `viewDidLoad` is usually too soon. Maybe you're okay there, but it's hard to tell. Second, why are you removing sublayers? That's the likely culprit for the "glitzy" behavior. (You're also working with frames there too.) My guess is that either the frame is essentially `CGRect.zero` or you are calling the code that is removing/creating layers more than you want.

Comment: Thanks, I'll play around with what you said see if that leads me anywhere.  I added the remove layers logic because I needed to update the view with a new gradient and it wasn't taking..How do I make it update otherwise?